# Bash shell if statement matching regex with curly braces {}

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, curly-braces

I've been writing a little bash script to aid less experienced Linux users with some commands.  One thing seems to be escaping me and that's using curly braces when doing pattern matching for an if statement.

```
regex="[A-Za-z0-9]/{5/}"
if [[ $2 =~ $regex ]]
then
  num=$2
else
  echo "Invalid entry"
  exit 1
fi
```

This should capture anything A-Z, a-z or 0-9 that is exactly 5 characters, should it not?

I've tried many times, many variations, many quotes, with and without escaping...  Nothing seems to be working:

```
+ regex='[A-Fa-f0-9]/{5/}'
+ [[ abcd1 =~ [A-Za-z0-9]/{5/} ]]
+ echo 'Invalid entry'
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is here:

```
regex="[A-Za-z0-9]/{5/}"
```

Should be:

```
regex="[A-Za-z0-9]\{5\}"
```

(watch backslashes)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had to escape that when using double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
regex="[A-Za-z0-9]{5}"
```

**Edit:** Another change you could try is

```
if [[ "$2" =~ $regex ]]
```

**Edit2:** If you just want to determine if `$2` is 5 characters long, you could try something like

```
if [ ${#2} = 5]
```

Comment: I have.  I've tried dozens of variations.  With and without the regex being in a variable:

regex="[A-Fa-f0-9]\{5\}"
regex="[A-Fa-f0-9]\{5}"
regex="[A-Fa-f0-9]{5}"

[[ $2 =~ [A-Fa-f0-9]\{5\} ]]
Same regex's as above + quotes around variables...  Nothing seems to be working.  Any other way to check that $2 is 5 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, works for me in bash version "GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release"

```
$ regexp="[[:alnum:]]{5}"
$ set -- "" abcde
$ [[ "$2" =~ $regexp ]] && echo y || echo n
y
$ set -- "" foo
$ [[ "$2" =~ $regexp ]] && echo y || echo n
n
```

Note that the right-hand side **must not** be quoted:

```
$ set -- "" abcde
$ [[ "$2" =~ "$regexp" ]] && echo y || echo n
n
```

You don't actually need a regular expression for this:

```
$ glob="[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]"
$ set -- "" abcde
$ [[ "$2" == $glob ]] && echo y || echo n
y
$ set -- "" foo
$ [[ "$2" == $glob ]] && echo y || echo n
n
```